# Clojure Synchronize Futures with Await

Tags: clojure, future, async-await

I have 3 long running tasks that I need to synchronize on.  They are independent, but the calling thread must wait until all three are finished before continuing.

I can create an agent for each task, and await on them, but agents aren't really the right semantic construct, since each agent will only be be called once.

What I really want is to await on 3 futures, or some approach that more closely resembles what I'm trying to achieve.

Can I await on futures instead of agents?

Edit:

I guess the answer is just simply to deref each future in the calling thread in a loop, which will block until they've all returned.  If I wanted to do "prep" work during this time, I could put the "defrefing" code itself in yet another future.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you mostly answered your own question. I'll add my 2 cents about how to do this though.

```
(defn many-futures
   [tasks]
  (let [futures (for [task tasks]
                  (future (task)))]
    (do-prep tasks)
    (doseq [completion futures]
      @completion)))
```

This will do your prep in parallel with all the futures, and then return after all the futures have completed. You could replace the doseq with `(doall (for ...))` if you actually want to use the results somewhere. Or, indeed, you could skip the `doall`, and then only block once the results are actually accessed. Even further, you could return the lazy-seq of futures itself, and then you can access any one of them via `deref` independently of the completion status of the others.